# Use title metadata as output filename ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

Is it possible to take the title metadata of input file, and just use that as the filename for the output file? I'm trying to encode a series of video files, and I'd like to automatically append the name of episodes to the filename, but I'm still very new to using ffmpeg and googling proved unsuccessful so far.

I'm trying to also write a batch script that'd encode the entire folder, and currently it looks like `for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i %%a -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s:1]overlay[subs];[subs]scale=960:720" -map 0:a:1 -acodec copy -sn test.mp4`

What should i put in place of "test.mp4"?

Comment: I would suggest that you replace `test.mp4` with `"%%~na.mp4"`. Additionally you should change `-i %%a` to `-i "%%a"` too.

Comment: To get title metadata: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=title -of csv=p=0 input.mp4`

Comment: @llogan, the question is specifically about `ffmpeg`, the OP did not mention having `ffprobe`, and as that is another thrid party application, they'd need to download it first. You should really make those things clear. Piotr Adryan, you need to clarify, if when you say the names of the episodes, those are essentially the name assigned to the mkv files, _(as assumed in my comment)_, or internally part of the files metadata itself, _(llogan's comment)_.

Comment: @Compo `ffprobe` is another tool from FFmpeg. "Make sure you download it first" seems superfluous to me. You should give the OP enough credit that they can determine these things for themselves (it's pretty obvious). It is not possible to get the title metadata using `ffmpeg` in a sane way. Uses such as this is exactly what `ffprobe` is for.

Comment: I know what `ffprobe` is @llogan, its a tool which did not form part of the question, or its tags, and is a separate download, which the OP did not mention they had.

Comment: @Compo If they don't have it I'm sure they can download it. Let them be the judge of the usefulness of my comment.

Comment: I never said that your comment wasn't useful @llogan, just that it should have made clear that the command you provided was for a different utility, which they would need to already have or download, to use! It appears to me as if mentioning that at the outset would have meant much less typing for the both of us! If the question was about WinRAR, and you posted code for 7-Zip, it would have been equally negligent not to specify that it is for a different non built-in tool which would need to be downloaded.

Comment: so i did a little more digging in the meantime - and 1: i do have `ffprobe`, 2: the metadata i want to extract is the title tag that is in the video stream, not file in general. Also, while your suggestion is helpful in normal circumstances Compo, wouldn't setting the output to` "%%~na.mp4"` just name them the same as input file? Yes, the names of episodes are the internal names, as suggested by Ilogan.

Comment: To explain further, what I'm guessing might be a solution would be to extract the title field of metadata for the video stream, and either pipe it into output filename, or output it into separate .txt file, and name the output video file using the .txt file, I found that `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map_metadata 0:s:v -f ffmetadata meta.txt` provides me with something close, as the output is ```;FFMETADATA1
title=Bravo at School!
encoder=Lavf58.51.101``` what i want is there to be only "Bravo at School!" without the encoder info or the header

Comment: @nokimemota To get the title of the video stream use `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream_tags=title -of csv=p=0 input.mkv`. You can use this as a variable in your batch file and avoid temporary text files. I don't use batch so I can't give you a complete answer. However, I could provide a bash example if that is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after being helped along by Ilogan, i managed to find an answer to what i want, even though it doesn't actually work properly yet, but i decided to write down here what i managed to find out so far, part for me, part for other poor souls.

So, following Ilogan's tip i managed to find out that `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream_tags=title -of csv=p=0 "%%a"` does indeed work and returns the metadata of title that's coded inside video stream.

Next was using that as a variable in a batchfile, which hs been answered several times, but I'll include it here as well:
You want to enclose the command in a for loop that has following look: `FOR /F "delims=" %%g IN ('ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream_tags^=title -of csv^=p^=0 "%%a"') do (SET title^=%%g)` the important parts: some tutorials show "tokens=*" instead of "delims=" which might work, but i think delims will work better here. the most important part is that the command contains an equal sign, and you need to use a caret sign `^` to escape and have the command line properly parse those.

The remaining problem is that with my script looking currently like this:

```
for %%a in ("*.mkv") do (
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream_tags^=title -of csv^=p^=0 "%%a"') do (SET title=%%g)
ffmpeg -i "%%a" -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s:1]overlay[subs];[subs]scale=960:720" -map 0:a:1 -acodec copy -sn "%title%.mp4"))
```

it seems that windows is running the first occurrence of the command in the file, and by then the title variable is still empty - as a result I'm getting files with name ".mp4" and still figuring out how to handle that

EDIT: OK, so i found out that what you need to do, is put `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start, and the title variable needs to be in exclamation marks, not percent marks, and it works! I tested it, and it properly creates the files, with the titles.

Comment: try ffprobe -v error select_streams v:0 stream_tags=title -of csv=p=0 1.mp4 it report Argument 'v:0' provided as input filename, but 'select_streams' was already specified. –